# Publishing HTML Field doesnt show up in Powerapps

Tags: powerapps-forms

I have a field of type Publishing HTML in SP List but it doesn't show up in Powerapps Form. I'm using Data Gateway to connect onprem SharePoint 2019 to powerapps. All the other fields appear in the form except this one  any thoughts?

[image: this is how it looks in SP List]

Answer (score 0):

Publishing HTML doesn't appear in the list of supported SharePoint column types (when connecting to SharePoint from a canvas app):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-sharepoint-online#lists